# Whether the use of 'are born' is formal

Tags: word-usage

*"When heroes are born, history is created."*

In the sentence, I'd like to know whether the use of 'are born' is formal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is formal.  Do you have an alternative that you think would be better?

Comment: **are born** is neither formal nor informal, but neutral register.  "Kittens *are born* blind."

Answer (score -1):

"When heroes are born, history is created."

In the above sentence "are born" is not specifically formal or informal. The sentence is written in a neutral register to deliver facts.

I can't think of an alternative.But maybe by understanding the meaning behind this sentence you can get your answer.Let’s start with how heroes come into being.The classic saying is that some are born great,some achieve greatness,and some have greatness thrust upon them. We all know that there have been people throughout history who have been blessed from birth with great gifts and inherent talent.We tend to call them child prodigies.
So, are heroes born or made? A true hero may be born with certain gifts, talents or abilities. But those are not what makes him a hero. A hero may get training from the best teachers,but in the end, it is what they choose to do, how they respond under pressure.If a hero must die, he gives his life in a worthy cause. He strives to his last breath, knowing that even if he does not save the day, he will have done his best. Who knows? His efforts may give the next hero the stepping stone from which to succeed. This is the attitude of many of our real life heroes who make our history.They were like you and me. Many of them were ordinary people, living ordinary lives - until suddenly they found themselves in circumstances which led them to act heroically. Many of our heroes lived in time of war, when the survival of our very nation was in the balance. Such times tend to make choices very stark - you are either prepared to sacrifice your life for your country, or you are not. However, others of our heroes did not live in wartime - or, at least, not when the country was under grave threat of being invaded. Even so, due to some circumstance or other, they came to feel that they must make hard sacrifices for the sake of others.

Comment: The answer starts off well, but I found this a hard-to-read wall of text with a lot of information unrelated to answering the question. Some editing and formatting would be helpful.